# XAML control not found in code-behind (Control.Template.FindName)

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2017, code-behind, findname

I'm trying to access a XAML control (the CustomMenuItem control, `BeverageMenuItem`) in the code behind, but it returns as `Null`.

```
<UserControl x:Class="DinerPOS.Restaurant.Windows.UserMenuInterface"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:customcontrols="clr-namespace:System.Windows.WPF.Controls;assembly=CustomControls"
             xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:DinerPOS.Properties"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
     <Image x:Name="MenuImage" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Cursor="/DinerPOS;component/Resources/Cursors/Hand.cur"
            Source="/DinerPOS;component/Resources/Images/Restaurant/Beverages/Beverage.png" Stretch="Fill">
            <Image.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu x:Name="MenuImageContextMenu" Background="White" Cursor="/DinerPOS;component/Resources/Cursors/Hand.cur" Width="175" Height="100">
                    <ContextMenu.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate x:Name="MenuImageTemplate">
                            <Grid x:Name="ContextMenuGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <customcontrols:CustomMenuItem x:Name="BeverageMenuItem" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </ContextMenu.Template>
                </ContextMenu>
            </Image.ContextMenu>
        </Image>
</UserControl>
```

**Code behind in UserMenuInterface.xaml.cs**

```
 CustomMenuItem BeverageMenuItem = (CustomMenuItem)MenuImageContextMenu.Template.FindName("BeverageMenuItem", MenuImage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The control you are searching for is defined inside a template. The template must be instantiated before you can search for controls contained in this template. This is when the templated control's `Loaded` event is raised, which in your case happens when the context menu is opened.

Code-behind of UserMenuInterface:

```
public UserMenuInterface()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  this.MenuImageContextMenu.Loaded += FindControl;
}

private void FindControl(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var BeverageMenuItem = this.MenuImageContextMenu.Template.FindName("BeverageMenuItem", MenuImage) as CustomMenuItem;
}
```